# Using SystemJS to import application modules in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm working on an Angular 2 with Typescript project using SystemJS.  Right now I find often we're having to do things like '`../../../`' to load components from other modules depending on how deeply nested we are in a given component.  It would seem like using SystemJS's map setting would allow me to have application-wide modules available for import without that horrible relative pathing approach, but I can't determine definitively if I can do that.  I'm also open to other ways to solve this.

Basically what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SecureHttpClient} from 'mySecurityModule'; //No ../../../

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private client: SecureHttpClient) {

  }
}
```

I tried the configuration below but it doesn't work (TS compilation fails).

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',


      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',

      // Internal Modules
      'mySecurityModule': 'app/secure/secure.module'

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I know there is likely other ways to do this, but again can't find anything definitive and it's a problem I'd really like to solve.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sort of off the topic, but would recommend using jspm to manage the systemjs configuration for external libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup typescript compiler to use base URL and import from there. In `tsconfig.json` add:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    ...
  }
```

then you can use app root as an absolute path. Something like

```
import {SecureHttpClient} from 'app/mySecurityModule';
```

instead of:

```
import {SecureHttpClient} from '../../../mySecurityModule';
```

Actual paths might be different for you.

However, I would recommend using some sort of Import extension for your editor (for example, [AutoImport](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) for VSCode), since some tools (AoT, CLI) might have an issue with this. Hopefully things will improve as tools get more mature (;

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried using baseUrl and while it works for tsc compilation (transpilation) it fails when loading the app in the browser with a 404 error.  Only when I do the `../../../` does it load the imported component correctly in the browser.  I'm using `tsc -w` and `lite-server` (a John Papa Browser Sync extension) to host the app.